# Error when adding conditional check in Dataweave

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1.

I have a Boolean field coming in from a CSV file that I want to add code to clean the data e.g. turn "Y", "Yes" into true or otherwise set it to false.

I only want the code to work if the field has a value.  If it is '' then I want to ignore it if it is populated then clean the data.  I thought adding a when statement would be the answer but it errors in preview.  How do I make this a conditional check?

**Dataweave code:**

```
(payload filter $$ > 2) map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    ({
        isPaid: true
    }
        when payload01.balanced != ''
        and ((lower payload01.balanced == 'yes'
        or (lower payload01.balanced) == 'y'
        or (lower payload01.balanced ) == 'true')
        otherwise {
        isPaid: false
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use below code snipped of Data Weave:
(payload filter $$ > 2) map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
({
    isPaid: true    when ((payload01.balanced != '')
                    and ((lower payload01.balanced) == 'yes')
                    or ((lower payload01.balanced) == 'y')
                    or ((lower payload01.balanced ) == 'true')) otherwise false
})
```

Comment: Please add some English text to explain your answer. Do not just post code answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (payload filter $$ > 2) map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
({
    isPaid: true
}
    when payload01.balanced?
    and ((lower payload01.balanced == 'yes'
    or (lower payload01.balanced) == 'y'
    or (lower payload01.balanced ) == 'true')
    otherwise {
    isPaid: false
})
```

})

Try this above.